# XGBoost difference in train and test features after converting to DMatrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, xgboost

Just wondering how is possible next case:

```
 def fit(self, train, target):
     xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train, label=target, missing=np.nan)
     self.model = xgb.train(self.params, xgtrain, self.num_rounds)
```

[image]
I passed the train dataset as **csr_matrix** with 5233 columns, and after converting to DMatrix I got 5322 features.

Later on predict step, I got an error as cause of above bug :(

```
 def predict(self, test):
     if not self.model:
         return -1
     xgtest = xgb.DMatrix(test)
     return self.model.predict(xgtest)
```

[image]

> Error: ... training data did not have the following fields: f5232

How can I guarantee correct converting my **train/test** datasets to DMatrix?

Are there any chance to use in Python something similar to R?

```
# get same columns for test/train sparse matrixes
col_order <- intersect(colnames(X_train_sparse), colnames(X_test_sparse))
X_train_sparse <- X_train_sparse[,col_order]
X_test_sparse <- X_test_sparse[,col_order]
```

My approach doesn't work, unfortunately:

```
def _normalize_columns(self):
    columns = (set(self.xgtest.feature_names) - set(self.xgtrain.feature_names)) | \
          (set(self.xgtrain.feature_names) - set(self.xgtest.feature_names))
    for item in columns:
        if item in self.xgtest.feature_names:
            self.xgtest.feature_names.remove(item)
        else:
            # seems, it's immutable structure and can not add any new item!!!
            self.xgtest.feature_names.append(item)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible explanation is that you have a feature level exclusively in your training data or exclusively in your testing data. This situation often happens after one-hot encoding, the result of which is a big matrix having one new feature (column/variable) for *each* level of your categorical features.

In your case it looks like feature "f5232" is either exclusively in the training dataset or exclusively in the test dataset. In either case, the model scoring is likely to throw an error (in most implementations of ML packages) because:

1. If exclusive to training: The model object (from training) will have a reference to this feature in its model equation.  During scoring (on test) it will throw an error saying "I am not able to find this column/feature".
2. If exclusive to test (less likely as test data is usually smaller than training data): The model object (from training) will *NOT* have reference to this feature in its model equation. During scoring (on test) it will throw an error saying "I've got this column but the model equation don't have this column". This error is also less likely because most implementations are cognizant of this case (they will ignore any extraneous columns).

Solutions:

1. The best "automated" solution is to keep only those columns, which are common to both training and test post one-hot encoding.
2. For ad hoc analysis: if you can not afford to drop the level of feature because of its importance then do stratified sampling to ensure that all levels of the feature appear in both training and test data.

Answer (score 3):

This situation can happen after one-hot encoding. For example,

```
ar = np.array([
        [1, 2],
        [1, 0]
])

enc = OneHotEncoder().fit(ar)
ar2 = enc.transform(ar)
b = np.array([[1, 0]])
b2 = enc.transform(b)
xgb_ar = xgb.DMatrix(ar2)
xgb_b = xgb.DMatrix(b2)

print(b2.shape) # (1, 3)
print(xgb_b.num_col()) # 2
```

So, when you have all zero column in sparse matrix, DMatrix drop this column (I think, because this column is useless for XGBoost)

Usually, I add a fake row to matrix which contents 1 in all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Such an issue occurred for me when RandomUnderSampler (RUS) method returned a np.array rather than a Pandas DataFrame with column names.

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
rus = RandomUnderSampler(return_indices=True)
X_rus, y_rus, id_rus = rus.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
```

I resolved the issue with this:

```
X_rus = pd.DataFrame(X_rus, columns = X_train.columns)
```

Basically taking the output of RUS method and creating a Pandas DataFrame out of it with column names from the original X_train data which was the input of RUS method.

This can be generalized to any similar problem where XGBoost expected to read column names but could not. Just create a Pandas DataFrame and assign the column names accordingly.