# Mismatch in feature_names in xgboost sklearn during multi-class text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, xgboost

I am trying to perform a multiclass text classification using xgboost in python (sklearn edition), but at times it errors out telling me that there is a mismatch in feature names. The odd thing is that at times it does work (perhaps 1 out of 4 times), but the uncertainty is making it difficult for me to rely on this solution for now, even though it is showing encouraging results without even doing any real pre-processing.

I have provided some illustrative sample data in the code that would be similar to what I'd be using. The code I currently have is as follows:

**Updated code that reflects maxymoo's suggestion**

```
import xgboost as xgb
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

rng = np.random.RandomState(31337)    

y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0])
X = np.array(['milk honey bear bear honey tigger',
          'tom jerry cartoon mouse cat cat WB',
          'peppa pig mommy daddy george peppa pig pig',
          'cartoon jerry tom silly',
          'bear honey hundred year woods',
          'ben holly elves fairies gaston fairy fairies castle king',
          'tom and jerry mouse WB',
          'peppa pig daddy pig rebecca rabit',
          'elves ben holly little kingdom king big people',
          'pot pot pot pot jar winnie pooh disney tigger bear'])

xgb_model = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), xgb.XGBClassifier())

kf = KFold(y.shape[0], n_folds=2, shuffle=True, random_state=rng)
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    xgb_model.fit(X[train_index],y[train_index])
    predictions = xgb_model.predict(X[test_index])
    actuals = y[test_index]
    accuracy = accuracy_score(actuals, predictions)
    print accuracy
```

The error I tend to get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 95, in <module>
    predictions = xgb_model.predict(X[test_index])
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 465, in predict
    ntree_limit=ntree_limit)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/core.py", line 939, in predict
    self._validate_features(data)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/core.py", line 1179, in _validate_features
    data.feature_names))
ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f20', 'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24', 'f25', 'f26'] ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f20', 'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24']
expected f26, f25 in input data
```

Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Comment: Just a guess, but are some of your rows in your training data missing f338?

Comment: my answer on exactly same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740885/xgboost-difference-in-train-and-test-features-after-converting-to-dmatrix/38887112#38887112

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are only scoring the model with features that it has been trained on. The usual way to do this is to use a `Pipeline` to package the vectoriser and the model together. That way they will both be trained at the same time, and if a new feature is encountered in the test data, the vectoriser will just ignore it (also note that you don't need to recreate the model at each stage of the cross-validation, you just initialise it once and then refit it at each fold):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline    

xgb_model = make_pipeline(CountVectoriser(), xgb.XGBClassifier())
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    xgb_model.fit(X[train_index],y[train_index])
    predictions = xgb_model.predict(X[test_index])
    actuals = y[test_index]
    accuracy = accuracy_score(actuals, predictions)
    print accuracy
```

Comment: This seems logical and I had high hopes that it would work, but for some reason it didn't. I have added a working example to my existing question that shows the issue.

Comment: Could it perhaps be that CountVectoriser() returns a sparse matrix whereas XGBClassifier() requires a dense one? Changing it to a dense one does however seem to eat up my memory footprint...

Comment: Your code doesn't throw an error for me ...maybe update to the latest version of sklearn? I'm on Python 3.4, scikit 0.17.1