# XGBoost testing features don't match training features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I appear to have mis-understood how XGBoost is supposed to be used. My model training appears to go well, but when I come to apply it to a hold out set the code complains that it's being fed new variables.

I'm working on the already closed Kaggle competition "Santander Customer Satisfaction" competition. You can see the datasets here:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-customer-satisfaction/data

Here's the code I'm running:

```
...list of modules...

seed = 342
np.random.seed(seed)

train_data = pd.read_csv("./train.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv("./test.csv")

test_id = test_data.ID

train_data = train_data.drop(["ID"],axis=1)
test_data = test_data.drop(["ID"],axis=1)

array = train_data.values

# Split-out validation dataset
X = array[:,1:368].astype(float)
Y = array[:,369].astype(int)

validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7

X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)

watchlist  = [(X_train, Y_train), (X_validation, Y_validation)]

ratio = float(np.sum(Y_train == 1)) / np.sum(Y_train==0)

model = xgb.XGBClassifier(
            base_score=0.5, 
            colsample_bylevel=1, 
            colsample_bytree=1,
            gamma=0, 
            learning_rate=0.5, 
            max_delta_step=0, 
            max_depth=3,
            min_child_weight=1, 
            missing=9999999999,
            n_estimators=25, 
            nthread=-1,
            objective='binary:logistic', 
            reg_alpha=0,
            reg_lambda=1,
            scale_pos_weight=1, 
            seed=7, 
            silent=True, 
            subsample=1
)


model.fit(X_train, Y_train, eval_metric="auc", eval_set=watchlist)


## # Submission
probs = model.predict_proba(test_data)
...
```

Here's what the script outputs:

```
[0] validation_0-auc:0.795057   validation_1-auc:0.791364
[1] validation_0-auc:0.804837   validation_1-auc:0.801891
[2] validation_0-auc:0.8113 validation_1-auc:0.809618
[3] validation_0-auc:0.813582   validation_1-auc:0.812916
[4] validation_0-auc:0.81944    validation_1-auc:0.817799
[5] validation_0-auc:0.822929   validation_1-auc:0.821458
[6] validation_0-auc:0.826112   validation_1-auc:0.82617
[7] validation_0-auc:0.830241   validation_1-auc:0.829682
[8] validation_0-auc:0.832868   validation_1-auc:0.832509
[9] validation_0-auc:0.835153   validation_1-auc:0.835
[10]    validation_0-auc:0.836704   validation_1-auc:0.834465
[11]    validation_0-auc:0.837821   validation_1-auc:0.834192
[12]    validation_0-auc:0.839605   validation_1-auc:0.834907
[13]    validation_0-auc:0.841186   validation_1-auc:0.836206
[14]    validation_0-auc:0.842604   validation_1-auc:0.836774
[15]    validation_0-auc:0.843251   validation_1-auc:0.837425
[16]    validation_0-auc:0.844243   validation_1-auc:0.837063
[17]    validation_0-auc:0.844695   validation_1-auc:0.837344
[18]    validation_0-auc:0.845865   validation_1-auc:0.838409
[19]    validation_0-auc:0.846729   validation_1-auc:0.837329
[20]    validation_0-auc:0.847179   validation_1-auc:0.836978
[21]    validation_0-auc:0.847953   validation_1-auc:0.83628
[22]    validation_0-auc:0.848195   validation_1-auc:0.836093
[23]    validation_0-auc:0.848502   validation_1-auc:0.836251
[24]    validation_0-auc:0.848797   validation_1-auc:0.83647
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so-script.py", line 74, in <module>
    probs = model.predict_proba(test_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 477, in predict_proba
    ntree_limit=ntree_limit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/core.py", line 941, in predict
    self._validate_features(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/core.py", line 1181, in _validate_features
    data.feature_names))
ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['f0', 'f1', 'f2',... long list of effs...

', 'f366'] [u'var3', u'var15', u'im ...long list of named variables...
expected f169, f168, f161, f160, ... long list of effs ....

... , f71, f72, f73 in input data
training data did not have the following fields: imp_ent_var16_ult1,      num_aport_var13_hace3, ... long list of named variables
```

As far as I can tell it's naming all of the variables suggesting that I've incorrectly applied the library, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Other scripts tend to apply more processing to the data before applying the algorithm, but I don't understand why that would be a problem as I'm leaving train/test in the same state.

Can anyone point out what I've done wrong?

Comment: It looks like that was a known bug at one point, see https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1091 and previous related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740885/xgboost-difference-in-train-and-test-features-after-converting-to-dmatrix. I'd try updating to the latest version of xgboost and seeing if it's still an issue for you.

Comment: I did find this issue, but it does not seem to fit in this instance as the last column of either my test or train datasets is filled with zeros.